# Through an example: what is parametric and non-parametric boostrap?

Tags: bootstrap

I cannot believe how abstractly some sources explain this, practically not explaining it at all.

So what's parametric and non-parametric bootstrap and how are they different?

Comment: You can view a nice tutorial here:  http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/5601/examp/parm.html

Comment: The distinction might be that the non-parametric bootstrap makes no assumptions about the distribution of the observed data, but merely calculates statistics directly from samples taken from the data. The parametric bootstrap assumes the observations follow a distribution and estimates the parameters for that distribution, then draws samples from the chosen distribution (with the estimated parameter, e.g. $\theta$) and calculates statistics. Both are used to calculate same sorts of statistics.

Answer (score 5):

I'll give you an example. Let's say you have the data set $x_1,\dots,x_n$, which you think comes from the normal distribution.

In **parametric** bootstrapping, you estimate the parameters of normal distribution $\hat\mu,\hat\sigma$, then you generate new sample from $x_1^*,\dots,x^*_n\sim\mathcal{N}(\hat\mu,\hat\sigma^2)$

You can generate as many samples $x_1^*,\dots,x^*_n$ as needed for you Monte Carlo simulation.

In **non-parametric** bootstrapping, you build empirical distribution function ([EDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function)), then generate the sample $x_1^*,\dots,x^*_n$ directly from EDF, not from the estimated normal distribution as in parametric bootstrapping.

It happens so that in some applications non-parametric bootstrapping leads to biased estimation, while parametric is unbiased, e.g. see G. Jogesh Babu, Eric D. Feigelson, "[Astrostatistics: Goodness-of-Fit and All That!](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~babu/mypdfpap/2006ASP-ADASS-XV-v351.pdf)", in Astronomical Data Analysis Software and Systems XV, ASP Conference Series, Vol. 351, 2006. The paper is about [K-S test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) critical values estimation.

Comment: I read that there can be parametric bootstrap with empirical CDF.

Comment: There's no way to explain everything by examples, that's why you have abstract descriptions: to capture the general case. If you have a particular concern, you should bring it up.

Comment: I'm just saying that the empirical CDF cannot be the distuinguishing feature if both parametric and non-parametric can utilize it.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: No, because it's an observation from my lecture notes, which I won't share.

Comment: How is parametric bootstrap different from a Monte Carlo simulation?

Comment: @Macond, bootstrapping is a kind of Monte Carlo simulation. Maybe not every kind of bootstrapping, but certainly those that I came across are